# AWS Dynamodb - Upsert using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was using putitem to insert json into dynamodb in my lambda.  This works fine but there may be times when I want to do partial updates - and only update parts of the Json that have changed or are new.

for example:

```
{ 
  fruits:
   {
      apple:
        {
          color: green
        }
       orange:
       {
         color: orange
       }
    }
}
```

I might then want to send an update like this:

```
{ 
  fruits:
   {
      apple:
        {
          color: red
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, this should only change the Json to this:

```
{ 
  fruits:
   {
      apple:
        {
          color: red
        }
       orange:
       {
         color: orange
       }
    }
}
```

Here is my current code:

```
data = json.loads(event['body'])
table.put_item(Item=data)
```

I have a partition key of `my_id` for example.

I have tried this:

```
            table.update_item(
                Key = { 'my_id': my_id },
                UpdateExpression = 'SET fruits= :my_data',
                ExpressionAttributeValues = {
                    ':my_data': data
                }
            )
```

But this will overwrite the fruits and remove the `apple` in the example above.

Is there a way to update parts of the json without having to specify what specific attributes you want to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some attribute names are reserved by AWS, there is a comprehensive list of these words: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

So instead of using `:data`, just rename it to something else, like `:itemdata`

Comment: yeah I got that part, but the problem I am having it that I want it to only update partials parts of the json. I have modifed my question to the core issue

Comment: From your example, you're modifying data which itself has `Map` type with another value of `Map` type, so it predictably replaces existing one without diving into it. If I were to do this, I would a) just use `put_item` and don't overthink it; or b) get value first, append new data to it and run `update_item` just the way you do now